# Expectation of exponential of Brownian motion

Tags: integration, brownian-motion, expectation

I want to compute the following expectation:

$\mathbb{E}[\int_0^\infty-e^{-\mu t+\sigma W_t}dt]$

where $W_t$ is a brownian motion, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ constant.

I am already stuck at computing the integral. I don't know how to solve something like $\int_0^\infty e^{W_t} dt$ to begin with. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are not supposed to compute the integral (whatever that means for a random quantity), only its expectation. Can you show your progress in this direction?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Apply Tonelli's (or Fubini's) theorem and use that the exponential moments of Gaussian random variables can be calculated explicitly.